# How to set UILabel text from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uilabel

I have problem with `UILabel` . Here is two file's `ViewController` and `MainClass` 
first is controller for nib file with `label1` outlet. Second file is a class with another label  `mainLabel` which contain text("Set from init method in MainClass"). I want set `mainLabel` to `label1` in `ViewController`.

In `init` method of MainClass i set text for `mainLabel.text`

```
mainLabel.text = @"Set from init method in MainClass";
```

and after that i call  `NSLog(@"%@",mainLabel.text);` but in console i have null

```
2011-12-14 10:31:31.048 ClassTask[1076:f803] (null)
```

and after then i call `label1 = newClass.mainLabel;` in `- (void)viewDidLoad` i have view with `label1` without text in my iPhone simulator.
//  ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainClass.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *label1;    
    MainClass *newClass;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;
@end
```

//  ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize label1;
-(void) dealloc{
    [label1 release];
    [super dealloc];
}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    newClass = [MainClass new];
    label1 = newClass.mainLabel;
}
@end
```

//  MainClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MainClass : NSObject {
    UILabel *mainLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
@end
```

//  MainClass.m

```
#import "MainClass.h" @implementation MainClass @synthesize mainLabel;
-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        mainLabel.text = @"Set from init method in MainClass";
        NSLog(@"%@",mainLabel.text);
    }
    return self; }
-(void)dealloc {
    [mainLabel release];
    [super dealloc]; 
} 
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it a NSString , its basically a text that you want to access in another ViewController.

another mistake i found

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize label1;
-(void) dealloc{
    [label1 release];
    [super dealloc];
}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    newClass = [MainClass new];
    **label1 = newClass.mainLabel.Text;  // its a label, so whenever you retrieve its value it would be like labelName.Text**
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to pass this `string` [in your code it mainLabel.text] from one controller to another controller then you can use `UISharedApplication`..follow this link.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486540/i-want-to-pass-data-from-one-view-controller-to-another-controller/8487095#8487095